# Remove the part with a character and numbers connected together in a string

Tags: python, string, nlp, python-re

How to remove the part with "_" and numbers connected together in a string using Python?

For example,

Input: `['apple_3428','red_458','D30','green']`

Excepted output: `['apple','red','D30','green']`

Thanks!

Comment: what will happen to ['green_', 'green_458aaa']?

Comment: My samples don't contain such cases so I don't consider for these two cases you mentioned. For sure it would be better if they can be considered. In this case the output for them should be ['green_','greenaaa']. In other words, remove the part where "_" and numbers both connected together. :)

Comment: Got it added possible solutions for few cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure which is needed, so present few options

Also list comp is better instead of map + lambda, also list comp is more pythonic, [List comprehension vs map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/list-comprehension-vs-map)

1. \d+ stand for atleast one digit
2. \d* stand for >= 0 digit

```py
>>> import re
>>> list(map(lambda x: re.sub('_\d+$', '', x), ['green_', 'green_458aaa']))
['green', 'greenaaa']
>>> list(map(lambda x: re.sub('_\d*', '', x), ['green_', 'green_458aaa']))
['green', 'greenaaa']
>>> list(map(lambda x: re.sub('_\d+', '', x), ['green_', 'green_458aaa']))
['green_', 'greenaaa']
>>> list(map(lambda x: x.split('_', 1)[0], ['green_', 'green_458aaa']))
['green', 'green']
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
my_list = ['apple_3428','red_458','D30','green']
new_list = []
for el in my_list:
    new_list.append(el.split('_')[0])
```

`new_list` will be `['apple', 'red', 'D30', 'green']`.

Basically you split every element of `my_list` (which are supposed to be strings) and then you take the first, i.e. the part before the `_`. If `_` is not present, the string will not be split.

Comment: While this works for the provided input, it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

Using regular expressions with `re.sub`:

```
import re

[re.sub("_\d+$", "", x) for x in ['apple_3428','red_458','D30','green']]
# ['apple_3428','red_458','D30','green']
```

This will strip an underscore followed by only digits from the end of a string.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
output_list = [x.split('_')[0] for x in input_list]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
input_list = ['apple_3428','red_458','D30','green']
output_list = []

for i in input_list:
    output_list.append(i.split('_', 1)[0])
```

You can simply split the string.